# Unable to get Authentication object in Spring Boot implemented Authorization Server

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have separate module for REST API and Authorization server, both implemented using Spring Security OAuth2 project in Spring Boot. This question is specifically related to Authorization Server.

The token flow is working fine and as expected. I'm able to generate a JWT token based on the user credentials passed to the authorization server and that gets decoded at the REST API module using the key.

Now the next step for me is to implement the UI of Authorization server which will have administrative sections like Client management, User Role Mapping etc etc. This will also have a profile section where user will be able to see/update his/her personal details.

To achieve this, I will be needing the info of logged in user so that I can get his/her details from the underlying data connection. I was expecting that if I pass Authentication class object in the controller function, I will get the details, just like we get it in Spring Security but that doesn't seem to work.

I believe there is some issue with the configuration I have done for Authorization Server and Spring Security. Here are those classes

Here is the authorization server configuration

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthorizationServerConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(this.dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(
                Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), jwtAccessTokenConverter()));

        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter())
                .tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder).tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();

        jwtAccessTokenConverter.setSigningKey("123");
        return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices(final TokenStore tokenStore,
                                              final ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        tokenServices.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        return tokenServices;
    }
}
```

and here is the spring security configuration

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final String AUTHENTICATION_URL = "/login";
    private static final String REFRESH_TOKEN_URL = "/oauth/token";

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        List<String> permitAllEndpointList = Arrays.asList(
                AUTHENTICATION_URL,
                REFRESH_TOKEN_URL);

        http.cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .antMatchers(permitAllEndpointList.toArray(new String[permitAllEndpointList.size()]))
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET")).logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/oauth/token")
                .antMatchers("/public/**", "/static/**", "/css/*", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/jquery/**",
                        "/materialize/**", "/favicon.ico");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I have already tried getting the object using SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() but it contains nothing.

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("profile")
public class ProfileController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProfileController.class);

    @GetMapping
    public String getView(Authentication authentication){
        logger.info("Authentication:: ", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
        return "profile";
    }
}
```

In the console I see this:

`c.h.s.a.controller.ProfileController     : Authentication::`

I'm expecting to get the Authentication Object so that I can extract the user principal and query the database to get profile information.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some methods of my guesses

1. Try delete `.tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)`, may be `CustomTokenEnhancer` has questions.
2. Try to use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`

Answer (score 0):

It's an old ticket but in case anyone is interested ...

There might be an actual problem, but there is also a problem with the log line - it won't print the value because it has no token in the log string:

```
logger.info("Authentication:: ", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
```

should be this:

```
logger.info("Authentication:: {}", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
```